# removing duplicate values from an array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to create a program in C that removes duplicate values in an integer array. My strategy is to first sort the array via a selectionsort function, and then call a function removedup that removes any consecutive, duplicate values in the array.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "simpio.h"

#define n 10

void GetArray(int a[]);
void SelectionSort(int a[]);
int FindMax(int a[], int high);
void swap(int a[], int p1, int p2);
int removedup(int a[]);
void printArray(int a[]);

main()
{
      int a[n];
      GetArray(a);
      SelectionSort(a);
      printf("The original, sorted array is\n");
      printArray(a);
      printf("The array with removed duplicates \n");
      printArray(removedup(a));
      getchar();
}


void GetArray(int a[])
{
     int i;
     for(i=0;i<n;i++)
     {
       printf("Enter integer# %d", i+1);
       a[i]=GetInteger();
     }
}

void SelectionSort(int a[])
{
     int i, max;
     for(i=0;i<n;i++)
     {
           max=FindMax(a,n-i-1);
           swap(a,max,n-i-1);
     }     
}

int FindMax(int a[], int high)
{
    int i, index;
    index=high;
    for(i=0;i<high;i++)
    {
       if(a[i]>a[index])
          index=i;
    }
    return index;
}
void swap(int a[], int p1, int p2)
{
     int temp;
     temp=a[p2];
     a[p2]=a[p1];
     a[p1]=temp;
}

int removedup(int a[])
{
     int i, count, OutArray[count], j;
     count=0;
     for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
     {
                        if(a[i]==a[i+1])
                        {
                                        a[i+1]=a[i+2];
                                        count++;
                        }
     }
     count++;
     for(j=0;j<count;j++)
     {
                       OutArray[i]=a[i];
     }

     return OutArray;                            
}
```

I have two questions:

1) How do I fix the error the compiler in giving me in the main body when calling removedup inside the printarray function, saying "invalid conversion from int to int*"? (line 22)

2) How do I accurately define the size of OutArray[] in the removedup function? Currently I have it defined as the size variable, but the value of this variable isn't accurately defined until after the declaration of OutArray.

Comment: You can do it faster in O(n) by the way

Comment: Read the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/), starting with section 6.

Answer (score 1):

Notice your prototypes ...

```
int removedup(int a[]);
void printArray(int a[]);
```

And also notice you're calling `printArray()` with the result of `removedup()`.

```
      printArray(removedup(a));
```

The result of `removedup()` is an int; `printarray()` requires a int[].
int and int[] are not compatible.

I suggest you remove duplicates and print array in two distinct statements.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I am not familiar with arrays as a data type, however. Would I modify the prototype to read "int[] removedup(int a[])"?

Comment: No, basically you can't return arrays from functions. Make your `removedup()` function change the input array or send it an output array. Afterwards, in another statement, print the modified array.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to fix the compiling problems after reading [comp.lang-c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html) on arrays and pointers.

After you get your array sorted, you can use the following function to remove the duplicates:

```
int dedup(int arr[], int size) {
    int curr = 0, next = 0;
    while (next < size) {
        while (next < size && arr[next] == arr[curr])
            next++;
    if (next < size)
      arr[++curr] = arr[next++];
    }
    return size ? curr+1 : 0;
}
```

It takes two arguments, the array and its size. The duplicates are removed in-place, which means that the array is modified, without allocating a new array to store the unique elements.

Remember that the `dedup` function expects the elements to be sorted! I've noticed you are using your own implementation of selection sort, which makes me think this is homework. In that case, I feel a little reluctant on giving you a complete solution, although understanding it should be a good exercise anyway.

**EDIT:** I should've explained the last line of code.

`return size ? curr+1 : 0;` is equivalent to:

```
if (size) 
    return curr+1;
else
    return 0;
```

Just a shorter way of saying the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your help, and this makes sense for the most part -- although could you explain what     return size ? curr+1 : 0; means? I'm not quite familiar with the notation.

Comment: I edited my answer because other people might have the same question in the future. Hope it helps. If it helped you, you should accept my answer =)